# I've been created. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.
>
> The finder did not create me.
>
> The creator did not know I was created.
>
> Perspective dictates my value.

**What am I?**

Point of clarification -

> the creator is a sentient being

Hint

> the creator did not know I was created at my inception, but has come to terms with the fact that he/she created me.

Hint #2

> because it is being sold, identify a profession that creates; a profession that something can be created unintentionally that may have unintended value.

Comment: @aprough While I understand your knee-jerk reaction to close this as too broad, there has not been one answer that fits completely. The line of “the creator did not know I was created” is the defining line, and I will contribute to provide hints. I voted to re-open.

Comment: Jason, I feel you. I have been through this. Things they cant answer are " too broad".

Comment: @prog_SAHIL It is a daunting task to try to moderate these forums effectively and efficiently, so the "too broad" flag seems to be applicable when there are multiple spaghetti answers. (Keep throwing out answers until something sticks) If those answers fit the question in its entirety, this would be too broad, but they do not.

Comment: I could have helped you unflag this, but I don't have the rep.

Comment: (There's a difference between "doesn't fit completely" and "is not ruled out by the question". It is *often* the case that a **correct** answer, as written, does not fit the question perfectly because the answerer is not inside the asker's head and doesn't get every detail or nuance. But a question that is *Too Broad* is one that permits multiple "adequate answer"s—at least plausible fits, not clearly ruled out by the question itself. An answer that is resoundingly a superior fit, provided early enough, *may* salvage a question that would otherwise be *Too Broad*; that hasn't happened here.)

Comment: My vote to close was because as it was, it was too broad.  There are multiple answers below that fit the riddle, so when I VTC'd it was too broad (you can see that if there are many answers that fit, but comments to the questions are that it is too far out of the box).  Your current hints have added a little definition to the intended answer, but it may still be too broad.  I have voted to reopen, but I still fear that this is too broad.

Comment: Okay I know there has been some debate, but I think this riddle deserves an upvote from all the people of the "profession" in question. Being of the profession myself, I can really appreciate it. I think this is very well put and an insiteful picture of an aspect of work many of us are very familiar with. I'd give more upvotes if I could. Props @JasonV!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I have another answer.

**You are a:**

> Software **Bug** or **Vulnerability** in a program feature.

**Explanation**

```
I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.
```

> The company that payed to have the software feature created (which also happens to contain a bug) did not know of the bug in the feature when it was released.

```
The finder did not create me.
```

> The person who finds a bug or vulnerability in a published software feature is not the programmer.

```
The creator did not know I was created.
```

> The creator/programmer made a mistake or oversight when programming a feature that lead to the creation of the bug or vulnerability (which he didn't catch in testing), but was not aware that he did so (and as you mentioned in the hint, once learning of the bug has to come to terms with the fact that he created it).

```
Perspective dictates my value.
```

> The possible damage a discovered bug or vulnerability can do is often a matter of perspective. For instance, when someone finds a bug in a Google product, they will pay varying amounts to the one that discovered the bug based on the perceived severity.

Comment: A b__ can be a feature! Nice one +1.

Comment: THIS. is the intended answer. Great job! (With Dexter's contribution as that was the intent, a bug is often sold as a feature!)

Comment: @ABcDexter Ah, yes. Great point! I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @JasonV Oh Awesome! I'm doing an edit, but feel free to edit further if you are particular about the wording. =) This was a fun one!

Comment: +1 - I like the answer, but I would like to point out that the finder sometimes create it (bad data/config), and the creator sometimes finds it (thorough testing).   Also, I am fairly certain that MS releases all the time with known bugs (point #1). ;)

Comment: @APrough I was thinking about that too. I guess the intent in this riddle is that it is more of a snapshot of a common scenario --one we're all to familiar with a lot of recent stuff in the news.

Answer (score 5):

You are a:

> Diamond.

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.

> The jewelry shops which sell diamonds typically do not own the mining companies responsible for unearthing new diamonds.

The finder did not create me.

> The mining companies do not actually manufacture the stones.

The creator did not know I was created.

> Diamonds are created through a natural process of compression over time, so the "creator" (i.e. Earth) does not "know" this is happening.

Perspective dictates my value.

> Diamonds are a lot more common than we are given to believe, and we only value them so highly because of a decades-long marketing and advertising push which has completely changed our perspective of them.

Comment: A bit of a stretch on the creator line don’t you think?

Comment: @JasonV: yes, I do think so, but thought I'd give it a shot anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a rough guess.

You are:

> Perfumes from Whale-poop

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me

> Shopkeepers that sell these perfumes obviously didn't find them.

The finder did not create me.

> The finder/perfume companies didn't create it. They just let it age.

The creator did not know I was created.

> The whale has no idea that his/her poop is being used as perfume.

Perspective dictates my value

> People who love perfumes pay millions of dollars for them, while others don't  value the perfume as much.

Comment: I.. wow. I learned something new today. That was _really_ interesting.

Comment: @VotBear it **really** is.

Comment: Wow. Way to think very far out of the box.

Comment: I think its vomit, not really poop. Vaguely recall seeing a yellow lump on some online photo previously...

Comment: @JasonV , wrote first thing that came to my mind :)

Comment: @Xenocacia https://www.livescience.com/26785-ambergris-sperm-whale.html

Comment: Ah right, my bad. Thanks for that, and we learn something new every day!

Comment: @Xenocacia, I am still new to puzzles, I learn a lot here on puzzling.se

Answer (score 2):

You are

> A priceless work of art

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.

> A work of art is (usually) sold well after the creator is deceased, and are usually "found" by art collectors, but sold at auction.

The finder did not create me.

> The art collector (or curator, or archivist, etc.) did not create the work of art

The creator did not know I was created.

> Usually, artists are/were just doing something that resonates with them.  The monetary value to others is of a secondary concern to them.  These artists do not know that decades (or centuries!) later that their work will become a masterpiece and be worth millions of dollars to art collectors.

Perspective dictates my value.

> Works of art are valued based on what people feel about them.    For instance, the da Vinci painting that recently sold for $450 million (US); some people think that is an inordinate amount of money for an old piece of canvas with some pigment on it, and some (whoever bought it), feel that it is worth every cent.  Of course, the artist who created it may not be concerned with the monetary value of a piece, but merely in the spiritual value that they used to create it.

Comment: The artist surely knows he created a piece of art?

Comment: ONly, 1 point off.

Comment: @JasonV -  The artist does not know he created an incredibly valuable piece of art.  He may think it, but he does not know it's worth until others see it.  <-- from an artist.

Comment: @APrough Ah, so your answer is the fact that it is the future value of a piece created now. Then this is the closest to the intended answer i have seen. The only slight qualm i have with it is, doesn't an artist intend on making a masterpiece on every project? In that case, he would know (or hope)

Comment: @JasonV - I can't speak for every artist, but some are trying to create a work that resonates for them; the value to others means nothing.  Of course, there are those that don't, and are purely in it to try to make money,  which is difficult (until you are dead).  I will try to flesh out my answer above to reflrec this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't think this is the answer, but it seems to fit.

You are:

> A web ad --like Google AdWords

Explanation:

> I'll use Google AdWords for the following breakdown for example.

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.

> Google is selling ranked results for companies' products to show up at the top of an individual's Google search --based on the words used in the search. Google is selling it, but didn't "find" it --the person surfing the web did.

The finder did not create me.

> The customer/person surfing the web using the Google search engine finds the Google Ad result at the top of the result list, but Google created it, not the person surfing the web.

The creator did not know I was created.

> This part is possibly debatable depending on how you view it, but Google didn't necessarily know the add was created as it is automatically created for the client. It does however track the clicks that the ad generates and charges business that is paying for the AdWord result.

Perspective dictates my value.

> The value of the AdWord is based entirely on the perspective of the customer --how interested the customer is in the product to click on the ad.

What am I?

> A Google AdWord --Or any other web ad provider that potentially works in a similar way. This is just the only one that I am familiar with.

Comment: Once again, I don't think this is the answer, but it sort of fit, so I added it. I'll keep chewing on it. I like the riddle!

Comment: I would argue that even though they don’t know which ad is created, they still know AN ad was created

Comment: @JasonV Yeah, I would agree. That's why I put the disclaimer. I see it's still not answered so I'll keep chewing on it. =)

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> A watch/time

**Explanation**

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.

> People sell watches, with time on them. That person did not manufacture the watch.

The finder did not create me.

> The manufacturer is not the one that discovered time.

The creator did not know I was created.

> The [Egyptians that created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time) the device that told the time did not know how time was created, or that time was created with the universe.

Perspective dictates my value.

> Time is relative. Perspective determines how long time has passed, or the value of time that passed by.

Comment: The Egyptians did not create time though, so your answer is a watch?

Comment: @JasonV I guess you could say that. I'll edit my answer. The Egyptians did create the first device to display time, though.

Comment: Now the answer is more relational, i.e.- the watch was invented because of time. The creator still knew he made a watch, the creator of time would be... ?

Comment: @JasonV At this point, the creator of time is indeterminant, but God could also be considered the creator of time. I don't know if that counts...?

Comment: But if it is God, wouldn’t he know what he created?

Comment: @JasonV I guess when I mentioned the Egyptians, I meant that they were "creating time" by making the first device to show it. But they didn't know what actually created it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> BULB

```
I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.
```

> Bulb is sold by edison patent but tesla found it .

```
The finder did not create me.
```

> Although Tesla found it , edison created it .

```
The creator did not know I was created.
```

> Maybe edison did not know he created EM(eletromagnetic) wave .

```
Perspective dictates my value.
```

> Differnt bulbs cost differnt ,like LED / filament ..people  choose what ever they like .

Comment: Good answer, but again I think the line about the creator is missing its value

Comment: Really out-of-the-box thinking ;D

Answer (score 1):

Quite surely :-

> A victim of human trafficking.

I am being sold by somebody that didn't find me.

> Someone else found the victim, carried him/her to the boss, who then sells him/her.

The finder did not create me.

> The person selling the child did not create him/her obviously.

The creator did not know I was created.

> Maybe the creator is god, who didn't knew the victim was created otherwise he/she wouldn't let that happen with the kid.

Perspective dictates my value.

> The victim is of infinite value since organisms cannot be valued in money, but for the buyer, the kid/victim is merely of 10-20$.

Everyone reading this, doesn't know how good of a life they have. Just to tell you, there are currently 1-2 million sexual assaults going on.
And another interesting fact, every second person in India goes through sexual assault atleast once before 18. 50-50 chance, fair enough?

Comment: Isn't it a quite a bit of a stretch when you say "Creator didn't know I was created" means God doesn't realize He/She created something? I would believe God is cleverer than that.(Also, edited in spoiler tags for you)

Comment: @Sid sir how to have spoiler tag? I want to tell those people that walk around everywhere doing god-god that see what your god is doing. Making children handicapped by birth, getting children raped, murdered, trafficked. I am quite sure even if there is a god, he wouldnt look on each of the 7 billion.

Comment: for spoiler tags use, ">!". And um... I believe the whole idea of God gives people hope to live on for things can be better. Whether that is correct or not, is a matter of debate and one that I am not at all interested in.

Comment: @Sid well sir debate is what we indians do. and thats the only thing we do.

Comment: Um.. I would rather prefer you don't bring countries and their people here. And let's try to avoid God for now, because it's (a) a touchy subject and (b) Can often lead to violation of the "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: @Sid right sir. sorry.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Puzzzling.SE Nice first try :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, you are a

> root vegetable

As,

> Vegetables are sold by vendors/retailers who generally do not find them
>  The finder is generally a middle-man/dealer who does not create them
>   The creator(farmer) does not come to know immediately when root vegetables are "created".
>  Polished vs raw vegetables have different price tags